# How to find vector for the quaternion from X Y Z rotations

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, quaternions

I am creating a very simple project on OpenGL and I'm stuck with rotations. I am trying to rotate an object indepentdently in all 3 axes: X, Y, and Z. I've had sleepless nights due to the "gimbal lock" problem after rotating about one axis. I've then learned that quaternions would solve my problem. I've researched about quaternions and implementd it, but I havent't been able to convert my rotations to quaternions. For example, if I want to rotate around Z axis 90 degrees, I just create the {0,0,1} vector for my quaternion and rotate it around that axis 90 degrees using the code here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-7_04.html (the most complicated matrix towards the bottom)

That's ok for one vector, but, say, I first want to rotate 90 degrees around Z, then 90 degrees around X (just as an example). What vector do I need to pass in? How do I calculate that vector. I am not good with matrices and trigonometry (I know the basics and the general rules, but I'm just not a whiz) but I need to get this done. There are LOTS of tutorials about quaternions, but I seem to understand none (or they don't answer my question). I just need to learn to construct the vector for rotations around more than one axis combined.

**UPDATE**: I've found this nice page about quaternions and decided to implement them this way: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html

Here is my code for quaternion multiplication:

```
void cube::quatmul(float* q1, float* q2, float* resultRef){
 float w = q1[0]*q2[0] - q1[1]*q2[1] - q1[2]*q2[2] - q1[3]*q2[3];
 float x = q1[0]*q2[1] + q1[1]*q2[0] + q1[2]*q2[3] - q1[3]*q2[2];
 float y = q1[0]*q2[2] - q1[1]*q2[3] + q1[2]*q2[0] + q1[3]*q2[1];
 float z = q1[0]*q2[3] + q1[1]*q2[2] - q1[2]*q2[1] + q1[3]*q2[0];

 resultRef[0] = w;
 resultRef[1] = x;
 resultRef[2] = y;
 resultRef[3] = z;
}
```

Here is my code for applying a quaternion to my modelview matrix (I have a `tmodelview` variable that is my target modelview matrix):

```
void cube::applyquat(){
 float& x = quaternion[1];
 float& y = quaternion[2];
 float& z = quaternion[3];
 float& w = quaternion[0];
 float magnitude = sqrtf(w * w + x * x + y * y + z * z);
 if(magnitude == 0){
     x = 1;
     w = y = z = 0;
 }else
 if(magnitude != 1){
     x /= magnitude;
     y /= magnitude;
     z /= magnitude;
     w /= magnitude;
  }

 tmodelview[0] = 1 - (2 * y * y) - (2 * z * z);
 tmodelview[1] = 2 * x * y + 2 * w * z;
 tmodelview[2] = 2 * x * z - 2 * w * y;
 tmodelview[3] = 0; 

 tmodelview[4] = 2 * x * y - 2 * w * z;
 tmodelview[5] = 1 - (2 * x * x) - (2 * z * z);
 tmodelview[6] = 2 * y * z - 2 * w * x;
 tmodelview[7] = 0;

 tmodelview[8] = 2 * x * z + 2 * w * y;
 tmodelview[9] = 2 * y * z + 2 * w * x;
 tmodelview[10] = 1 - (2 * x * x) - (2 * y * y);
 tmodelview[11] = 0;

 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glPushMatrix();
 glLoadMatrixf(tmodelview);
 glMultMatrixf(modelview);
 glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, tmodelview);
 glPopMatrix();
}
```

And my code for rotation (that I call externally), where `quaternion` is a class variable of the cube:

```
void cube::rotatex(int angle){
 float quat[4];
 float ang = angle * PI / 180.0;
 quat[0] = cosf(ang / 2);
 quat[1] = sinf(ang/2);
 quat[2] = 0;
 quat[3] = 0;
 quatmul(quat, quaternion, quaternion);
 applyquat();
}

void cube::rotatey(int angle){
 float quat[4];
 float ang = angle * PI / 180.0;
 quat[0] = cosf(ang / 2);
 quat[1] = 0;
 quat[2] = sinf(ang/2);
 quat[3] = 0;
 quatmul(quat, quaternion, quaternion);
 applyquat();
}

void cube::rotatez(int angle){
 float quat[4];
 float ang = angle * PI / 180.0;
 quat[0] = cosf(ang / 2);
 quat[1] = 0;
 quat[2] = 0;
 quat[3] = sinf(ang/2);
 quatmul(quat, quaternion, quaternion);
 applyquat();
}
```

I call, say `rotatex`, for 10-11 times for rotating only 1 degree, but my cube gets rotated almost 90 degrees after 10-11 times of 1 degree, which doesn't make sense. Also, after calling rotation functions in different axes, My cube gets skewed, gets 2 dimensional, and disappears (a column in modelview matrix becomes all zeros) irreversibly, which obviously shouldn't be happening with a correct implementation of the quaternions.

Comment: Do you want help with quaternions, or with rotating an object?

Comment: well I've gone with the quaternions path and wrote code so it'd be helpful if you have a quaternion-involving solution for rotation. what i simply need to implement is to be able to rotate an object with 3 degrees of freedom in 3D space

Comment: Maybe the book "Quaternions and Rotations Sequences" from Jack Kuipers may help you. There are lots to say about X-Y-Z rotations (aka Euler angles). For example are you rotating around the old X axis or the new one (the axis 'attached' to the object you are rotating)?

Comment: I need to rotate around world coordinates, not the attached one. (else it would be easy with regular rotations/Euler angles)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way. If you have three Euler angle rotations for the X, Y, and Z axes, turning them into a quaternion and then into a matrix won't help you. Gimbal lock arises because of the *representation* of your desired rotation. If you store the rotation that you want as X-Y-Z Euler angles, then you will get Gimbal lock.

You need to store your *desired* orientation as a quaternion to get the advantages. That is, it's possible to take a current orientation as a quaternion and then ask the question "how do I rotate that around the Z axis by 90 degrees and use that as my new orientation?", but it's not useful to ask "my current orientation is defined by these X-Y-Z Euler angles, how do I turn that into a quaternion?".

A full treatment of the relevant parts of quaternions would be pretty lengthy.  It's worth noting that the site you linked to appears to really be talking about axis-angle rotations, not quaternions.

**Edit:** The code you posted is correct except that the signs for `tmodelview[6]` and `tmodelview[9]` are wrong.

Comment: thanks. I understand that I need to be storing my orientation (hence, a quaternion), and forget about angles in that one. your link is quite helpful, but one thing I still don't understand is that the question that you are talking about: "how do I rotate that around the Z axis by 90 degrees and use that as my new orientation?"

Comment: Quaternion multiplication. If you have a quaternion `q` that refers to your current orientation, and a quaternion `r` that is a rotation around the Z axis by 90 degrees, then the quaternion `r*q` is your new orientation. An exact parallel to matrix multiplication, really.

Comment: i've done the multiplication using the link here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html but as soon as i try to rotate on another axis, i lose a dimension (a column becomes all zero) and the object becomes a 2d plane, irreversibly.

Comment: There's little to no way to debug that without seeing the code.

Comment: Check your signs. I think the signs on the matrix creation for `tmodelview[6]` and `tmodelview[9]` are incorrect.

Comment: wow, that was the problem. it now works perfectly. thank you a lot. i'd be happy if you update the answer as such. i've spent literally hours on this. thank you a lot, again.